# Why is $V$ really the class of all sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $V = \{ x \mid x = x \}$.
I want to clearly see that $x \in V $ iff $x$ is a set.
In other words,
$ x = x$ iff $x$ is a set...and here I get into problems. How can I continue the argumentation?

Ok I clearly see the point intuitively, but now I need to have solid basis and consequently I need a rigorous proof.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Just to be clearer: why don't we refer to the class of all sets as:
$W = \{ x \mid \exists x \}$?
In this way every sets $y$ trivially satisfies $\exists y$ and, conversely, if a class A satisfies $\exists A$, it must be a set because we are working with first-order logic (so we can't use quantifiers on classes).

Edit 2:
My apolgies for the silly question. As you can imagine, my problem is the lack of any knowledge of mathematical logic. I these days, I have seen same basis and now everything appears clear.
Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I think this relies greatly on the context and convention. For example, if you assume that $x$ being a member of $V$ requires $x$ to be a set, the statement $x = x$ can be replaced by any tautology that does not necessarily involve $x$.

Comment: It's clear why this question is a bit confusing. What's not clear is what knowledge you have or don't have about mathematics, logic, first-order logic in particular, and set theory.

Comment: LaTeX tip: `\mid` generates `|` with proper spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of set theory, we work inside a universe $\langle V,\in\rangle$ which satisfies the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ (or a related variant).

First of all, $\exists x$ is not a valid sentence, or even a formula. $x$ is a term, and formulas are built from relations between terms.

Secondly, in the context of first-order logic, $\exists x\varphi(x)$ is true in $M$ if and only if there is some $m\in M$ such that $M\models\varphi(m)$. In set theory things which exist are called sets, and things exist if and only if they satisfy $x=x$. So $\langle V,\in\rangle\models m=m$ if and only if $V$ "thinks" that $m$ exists, in which case we say that $m$ is a set.

What you wrote in the comments to the other answer, that not everything is a set is wrong to *some* degree. Inside the universe of set theory, everything is a set, proper classes do not exist inside the universe of set theory, but we are able to say intelligent things about them *from the meta-theory* (they are subsets of $V$, when we consider $V$ a set in a larger universe of set theory, for example).

In set theory the things that exists are called sets, just like in the context of $\Bbb Q$ things which exist are called "rational numbers". Other things may be called irrational numbers, or they might not be called "numbers" at all.

Answer (score 0):

In set theory, everything is a set and $x=x$ is true for all sets. Hence $V$ is the set of all sets. Using Russell paradox you can then conclude no such set $V$ exists

Comment: Not as a set indeed. That's why you should call it the class of all sets. As a class it 'exists' (whatever that is, if it comes to abstract concepts).

Comment: Thank you, but the point is another.
In set theory not everything is a set, and if it is true that $x = x$ is valid for any set, I don't understand why it is true only for sets and not - for example - for proper classes.